# Do not upload image if already upload one in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Under a particular id I uploaded an image and next time under the same id cannot upload image how is it possible.
Using two tables one table called user for basic info and other called files for upload image . id from user is also saved as userid in files table.
Am I missing something In viewpage .

Answer (score 0):

if you want the a single user to only upload 1 image, you can check the images table before inserting a new image.

Assuming your database tables look like this:
users: id, name, email
images: id, user_id, path

you would have to do an eloquent query like this:

```
$image = Images:where('user_id', $logged_in_user_id)->first();
if ($image == null) {
    // user can upload an image
}
else {
    // user already uploaded an image
}
```

You can also setup unique key constraint on images table, to disallow duplicated user_id in there.